# A man was born in the 18th Century. In certain year of his life, the square of his age was equal to the year. What year was he born?

Tags: mathematics

He was born in the 18th century, the square of his age was equal to the year he was born.

Comment: the title and the problem statement don't match.  one says the square of his age equals the year, the other says it equals the year he was born.

Comment: is it asking "what number's square is between 1700-1800"

Answer (score 4):

Of course he was born in

> 1722 = 42*41. In 1764=42*42 his age was 42.

Update:

> The answer is given according to the *title*. If the *text* interpretation is correct, the answer is indeed 1764.

Comment: Tried the next possible number, but that required being born in a different century to fit the rest of the puzzle.